# WebView ¿cual es el evento que se ejecuta al tocar un enlace, imagen, articulo dentro del WebView?

Tags: java, android-studio, funciones, eventos, webview

la verdad es que soy nevo aprendiendo y no he encontrado informacion sobre el problema, el problema es el siguiente:

estoy haciendo una aplicacion que muestre una pagina web en un WebView, lo que quiero saber es cual es el evento, metodo o funcion que se ejecuta al tocar un enlace o imagen de un articulo. Para desplegar una accion al tocar dicho articulo o imagen

tengo lo siguiente:

```
MyWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                if(mInterstitialAd.isLoaded())
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

el problema es que el codigo que muestro me ejecuta un evento cada touch, y yo lo que busco es el evento que se ejecuta al presionar un articulo.

no se si me explique bien, la verdad es que soy nuevo y no tengo mucha experiencia.
si responderian, se los agradesco mucho.

Answer (score 1):

Si deseas detectar cuando das click a un enlace de una página web que se encuentra dentro de una `WebView` debes config un `WebViewClient`, y en su método `onPageStarted()` es donde se llama inicialmente cada vez que das clic en un elemento, crea la clase que extiende de `WebViewClient` :

```
public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        Log.i(TAG, "onPageStarted() click en enlace: " + url);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
       return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

    }
}
```

Cargarías de esta forma la clase:

```
  webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
```

y posteriormente tu pagina web:

```
   webView.loadUrl("https://es.stackoverflow.com/");
```

Comment: Noto que con este método solo ingresa cuando el clik es sobre un hiperviculo pero si quisiera detectar un click sobre otro objeto determinado (incluso uno que yo sepa su nombre) que metodo debo utilizar?